# How to have a multiple line prompt terminal?

Tags: shell, term

Using mainly `ansi-term`,`term` or `vterm` I'd like the prompt to contain a line with informations for directory,user and git, whilst the actual input prompt line to be below.

I've heard of `zsh` though doubt that emacs hasn't something already hidden onbard. How would you achieve such a shell prompt?

[image: Terminal with multiline prompt]

Comment: Voting to close -- this isn't an Emacs question; it's just a general shell/terminal question.

Comment: I have an eshell prompt like Ys-theme from oh-my-zsh. You can start reading 'em-prompt.el' file.